# Optimizing MongoDB indexing multiple field with multiple query

Tags: mongodb, performance, optimization, indexing, database

I am new to database indexing. My application has the following "find" and "update" queries, searched by single and multiple fields

```
                reference | timestamp | phone | username | key | Address
update              x     |           |       |          |     |                     
findOne                   |     x     |   x   |          |     |         
find/limit:16             |     x     |   x   |    x     |     | 
find/limit:11             |     x     |       |          |  x  |    x
find/limit:1/sort:-1      |     x     |   x   |          |  x  |    x
find                      |     x     |       |          |     |                 


1)update({"reference":"f0d3dba-278de4a-79a6cb-1284a5a85cde"}, ……….  
2)findOne({"timestamp":"1466595571", "phone":"9112345678900"})
3)find({"timestamp":"1466595571", "phone":"9112345678900", "username":"a0001a"}).limit(16)
4)find({"timestamp":"1466595571", "key":"443447644g5fff", "address":"abc road, mumbai, india"}).limit(11)
5)find({"timestamp":"1466595571", "phone":"9112345678900", "key":"443447644g5fff", "address":"abc road, mumbai, india"}).sort({"_id":-1}).limit(1)
6)find({"timestamp":"1466595571"})
```

I am creating index

```
db.coll.createIndex( { "reference": 1 } ) //for 1st, 6th query
db.coll.createIndex( { "timestamp": 1, "phone": 1, "username": 1 } ) //for 2nd, 3rd query
db.coll.createIndex( { "timestamp": 1, "key": 1, "address": 1, phone: 1 } ) //for 4th, 5th query
```

Is this the correct way?

Please help me

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have done looks fine.  One way to check if your query is using an index, which index is being used, and whether the index is effective is to use the `explain()` function alongside your `find()`.

For example:

```
db.coll.find({"timestamp":"1466595571"}).explain()
```

will return a json document which details what index (if any) was used.  In addition to this you can specify that the explain return "executionStats"
eg.

```
 db.coll.find({"timestamp":"1466595571"}).explain("executionStats")
```

This will tell you how many index keys were examined to find the result set as well as the execution time and other useful metrics.